# Check minimum values from a multidimensional list and replacing the list which has minimum values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python I have a multidimensional list which has following components[[x1,y1,z1,w1].....[xn,yn,zn,wn]]. I want to check minimum value of wth element and for the minimum value I want to replace the whole list with new list

For Example:

`list1=[[1,2,3,4,5][2,3,4,5,6]]` check minimum value of list 1
here minimum value is 5 in `list1[0]`
I want to replace the whole `list[0]` with suppose `[3,4,5,6,7]`
How can I do it
I have done an example but its not working can anyone help me out how to do it

```
if len(prefetchBuf) >=prefetchBuffer:
        for addr in prefetchBuf:
            minimum =min(prefetchBuf[addr[-1]])
            prefetchBuf.remove(addr)
            prefetchBuf[addr][0]=x
            prefetchBuf[addr][1]=stride
            prefetchBuf[addr][2]=newaddr
            prefetchBuf[addr][-1]=confidence
```

It is giving

```
prefetchBuf[addr][0]=x
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list
```

Comment: *"..minimum value is 5 in list1[0]"*. Do you mean maximum value?

Comment: its the minimum of the last element in all sublists @Austin

Comment: yes @Austin he is saying right

Comment: Can you help me@DerekEden

Comment: Seems that your prefetchBuf is a 2-d list  and so addr is a list. So you can't have addr as the list index

Comment: That's the sample code and I know that is wrong I want to know how can I implement it correctly @pokfungChan. Thank you all for reply can u help me with this code

Answer (score 1):

not sure what your real data looks like, but hopefully this will in principle help you...working with your example data:

```
list1=[[1,2,3,4,5],[2,3,4,5,6]]
list2=[3,4,5,6,7]
last_vals = [sub[-1] for sub in list1]
loc = last_vals.index(min(last_vals))
new = [sub if i != loc else list2 for i,sub in enumerate(list1)]

output:

[[3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
```

EDIT: if there are multiple occurrences of the minimum value, you can replace all sublists using the following:

```
min_val = min(last_vals)
new = [sub if sub[-1] != min_val else list2 for sub in list1]
```

Comment: Calculating index would not be the best approach here. Why not just compare the minimum value while iterating over the list?

Comment: Adding to that, if minimum value is available in multiple sublists, this replace only the first of them.

Comment: good point..added an edit to change all if desired..if the OP wants to change the nth...can do that edit but think it's outside the original question

Comment: There's no need for two list comprehensions in the edit. You could do: `[[3,4,5,6,7] if x[-1] == min_val else x for x in list1]`.